# How to unit test this

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, moq

I am trying to write my first unit test for one of my service layers. I am using nunit and moq (latest versions).

I have a repo but I will mock that out that is no problem.

```
 public void Create(string email, int id)
     {
            User user = Repo.GetUserByEmail(email); // mock this out. and return a mocked user.

            if user != null)
            {

                // check permission
                var  clearence = GetPermissions(user, PermissionTypes.Add, id);

                // some other stuff

            }
    }


    private static List<Permissions> GetPermissions(User user, PermissionTypes PermissionNeeded, int id)
    {
        List<PermissionLevel> clearence = user.PermissionLevels.Where(u => u.id == id &&
                                                                                    (u.Permission.Name == PermissionNeeded || u.Permission.Name == PermissionTypes.Owner)).ToList();
        return clearence;
    }
```

So that is what I have.

Now what is getting me is this clearance. I am not sure how to do it. I am not sure if I have to make a user object that has a permissionLevels in it that contains a id.

I am not sure if I could mock it up but I doubt it since it is private.

The second problem is I am not sure how to create an "id" as the "id" is in a domain class that has a private set because well that was the standard used for nhibernate.

So I am not sure how to get around that.

Comment: What code do you want to test? `GetPermissions` or "// some other stuff" ?

Comment: dv-Jan de Vaan- the other stuff I guess. What basically is an if statement to check permission then if good create a task(another thing in my repo). If not then validation error. I need to get by this method first though and it has to return a counter > than 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, assuming you're mocking GetUserByEmail, you can have it return a user that contains a sample set of permissions.

Comment: would that autofixture + auto moq help me to make these objects. like I said I don't know how to make the id since it is a private set(since like I said that seems to be a standard way of doing it with nhibernate to make sure auto generated id cannot be set).

Answer (score 0):

I would wrap the Repo.GetUserByEmail method in a separate class and inject this into your class. Something like this:

```
public class YourClass
{
    private readonly UserProvider _userProvider;

    public TestedClass(UserProvider userProvider)
    {
        _userProvider = userProvider;
    }

    public void Create(string email, int id)
     {
        User user = _userProvider.GetUser(email, PermissionTypes.Add, id); // mock this out. and return a mocked user.

        if (user != null)
        {

            // check permission
            var  clearence = GetPermissions(user, PermissionTypes.Add, id);

            // some other stuff

        }
     }        
}

public class UserProvider
{
    public User GetUser(string email, PermissionTypes.Add, id)
    {
        return Repo.GetUserByEmail(email);
    }
}
```

Thus, you can stub the UserProvider class and always have full control over the user in the test.

Remember to test the UserProvider class as well ;o)

Regards, 
Morten